# change C++ code from Win32 platform to WinCE

Tags: c++, windows, windows-ce

I have a Win32 application in C++.
What I want to produce is an .exe for this application compatible with WinCE. I thought it is better to change my platform. But when I run the code in smart device platform, there are many errors! What is the best way to change the source code?

Answer (score 2):

The road could be simple or very difficult.  Depends on the source code. It's rare that code written without thought of devices in the first place will just work without change.  The first step is to import all of the code into a Smart Device project targeting your device SDK and try to build it.  The compiler and linker will give you an indication of the work you'll have to do.

Some of the larger pain points you might face are:

- Windows CE is a subset of Win32, so it's possible, maybe even likely, that the code uses APIs not available in CE.  You'll have to find alternatives for those.
- Windows CE is very heavily biased toward Unicode and most Win32 APIs don't even have ASCII version in CE.  A load of desktop code is ASCII based.  You'll have to rework all of that code.  Using the TCHAR macros can help keep the code backward compatible.
- If the code uses any inline ASM, it could make life difficult, especially if you're moving to ARM where the code is different and inline ASM isn't supported.
- The UI/GDI stuff in CE is substantially more limited than under the desktop.  UI can be tough to port easily.
- Are you using third-party libraries?  If so, do they have CE support, or can you get the source code?

There a lots of other small "gotchas", but without knowing anything about your code base, it's tough to say more.  Again, the compiler and linker will be the first things to give you an idea how much work you have ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend to keep win32 version where it is a lot easier to develop and debug code. On some windows ce devices you might not be able to run your code in debugger.

If your application is compiled without UNICODE then you will have to convert you CHAR* strings to WCHAR* strings every time you call API functions that require strings. You will save yourself a lot of time if you simply turn you application into UNICODE. Otherwise use TCHAR everywhere.

You will find that some code needs special version for Windows CE platform and different     for Win32. Then you can use if-defs:

```
#if defined(_WIN32_WCE)
/// windows ce code version
#else
/// win32 code version
#endif
```

If you want to port to Windows CE 5.0 then be prepared for memory limitations: 32MB per process, but in fact less than that is available to your code. Your device can actually have 120+MB or RAM, to access it you can use memory mapped files.